# Auth0 SSO for a SPA

Tags: single-sign-on, auth0

In the past, I've successfully setup SSO with Google and Microsoft and now I am trying to setup Auth0 in order to give login access through other identity providerers such as Okta.

In my single page application, the steps have always been similar for both Google and Microsoft:

1. Click on Google/Microsoft SSO button
2. Identify within the Google/Microsoft popup window
3. If the login is correct, a successful callback is triggered containing a Google "credential" or a Microsoft "accessToken"
4. I pass this token to my backend
5. the backend returns the JWT token to use for all future interactions

Now with Auth0 things get weird (i'm using https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react):

1. Click on Auth0 SSO button
2. Auth0 redirects to a new window (side question: is it even possible to keep the user in the main window using a popup window like Google/Microsoft do?)
3. If the login is correct, I get redirected back to the page with the information of the logged user, but I have no access to an access token.
   Under the hood I can see a network call that responds so there is the token, but with the library i'm using i have no idea how to access it and send it to the backend:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJk...",
    "id_token": "eyJhbGc...",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

In order to get a token I have to call a getAccessTokenSilently API, the returns either an "Error: Consent required" error, or an "Error: Timeout".

I'm not sure how to get this to work. If anyone has a solution I would be very pleased to hear it.

similar problems listed below:

- https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-a-new-access-token-by-current-access-token-or-refresh-token-in-auth0-react/103386/2

Thanks